# ¿Cómo puedo remplazar los datos diagnoles de una matriz por un dato especifico en Java?

Tags: java

Me encuentro realizando un ejercicio observado en una plataforma. Cuál consiste,  crear una matriz con un tamaño de filas y columnas "N" y modificar los datos diagonales por un dato específico: el número "5". Me encuentro en el paso final, a continuación mi código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Variables
    int matriz[][], N,M;
    //Datos a ingresar
    System.out.print("Ingrese el tamaño de filas de la matriz: ");
    N = lectura.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Ingrese el tamaño de columnas de la matriz: ");
    M = lectura.nextInt();
    matriz = new int[N][M];
   //Proceso
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<M; j++){
            System.out.print("Ingrese el valor para A["+i+"]["+j+"] = ");
            matriz[i][j] = lectura.nextInt();
        }
    }
    ImprimirMatriz("Los datos de la matriz son: ",matriz,N,M);
    
    int diagonalSecundaria[]=new int[matriz.length];
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<M; j++){
            if((i+j)==matriz.length-1){
                diagonalSecundaria[i]=matriz[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    //Mostrar los resultados del diagonal
    System.out.println("\nEl diagonal secundario es: ");
    for(int elemento:diagonalSecundaria){
        System.out.print("\t"+elemento);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    //Remplazar los números diagonales por 5 
    // ¿?
}
public static void ImprimirMatriz(String mensaje, int A[][], int N, int M){
    System.out.println("\n"+mensaje+"\n");
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<M; j++){
            System.out.print("\t"+A[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

> Tengo una duda aparte, ¿es posible realizar una validación de números enteros con la estructura mostrada? Aún no he visto un ejemplo, quizás ¿Do-While? Es posible realizar dicha matriz con la petición de datos dentro de ese método en la línea de código comentada "//Proceso" encargada de pedir los datos a ingresar.

Muchas gracias por todo su apoyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es una matriz bidimensional de fila y columnas N solo necesitarías capturar **N** y con ello declarar la matriz

```
matriz = new int[N][N];
```

para cambiar los valores, dé la diagonal secundaria solo debes hacer uso de la misma lógica en la que obtuviste la diagonal secundaria solo que esta vez en vez de guardarlos en un array vas establecer en cada iteración el valor que lo ha de remplazar

```
 System.out.println("\nEl diagonal secundario es: ");
    for(int elemento:diagonalSecundaria){
        System.out.print("\t"+elemento);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    //Remplazar los números diagonales por 5 
    
    System.out.println("Ingresa numero que remplazara la diagonal secundaria");
    int reemplazo=lectura.nextInt();


    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<M; j++){
            if((i+j)==matriz.length-1){
               matriz[i][j]=reemplazo;
            }
        }
    }

     System.out.println("");
     ImprimirMatriz("Matriz con dato reemplazado",matriz,N,M);
```

Comment: con respecto a tu duda, mediante condicionales puedes validar el valor que se va ingresando en cada posición de la matriz bidimensional, si quisieras solicitar un nuevo valor en la posición donde antes ya se había ingresado un dato siendo este invalido, usando while o do while seria lo apropiado